# Navier Stokes: $(u⋅∇)u$ vs $u⋅∇u$

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, notation, vector-fields, navier-stokes

I can find this term stated both ways in different literature.

Are they equivalent?

It's weird because the dot is a dot product in (u⋅∇), but ∇u being a gradient of a vector field, would (presumably) produce a (jacobian?) matrix which would turn that dot-product dot into a regular vector-matrix multiply where I have to swap the matrix and the vector (because as it's written, the vector will be on the left side).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $\vec{u}$ is a vector field $\vec{u} = (u_{x},u_{y}, u_{z})^T$ where $u_{x}, u_{y}$ and $u_{z}$ are scalar fields. So writing things out for clarity we have:
\begin{align}
(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\vec{u} &= (u_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +u_y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+u_z\frac{\partial}{\partial z})\vec{u} \\
&= (\vec{u}\cdot\nabla u_{x},\vec{u}\cdot\nabla u_{y},\vec{u}\cdot\nabla u_{z})^T
\end{align}
Furthermore:
\begin{align}
\vec{u}\cdot\nabla\vec{u} &= \vec{u}\cdot(\nabla u_x,\nabla u_y,\nabla u_z)^T \\
&= (\vec{u}\cdot\nabla u_{x},\vec{u}\cdot\nabla u_{y},\vec{u}\cdot\nabla u_{z})^T
\end{align}
The second expression is indeed equivalent to the first. The first way of writing it is definitely more explicit and clear though. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576577/treating-expressions-of-the-form-vec-x-cdot-nabla-vec-y-what-is-the-order?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions are equivalent.  For the second form, you *left*-multiply by the vector at the end to return to a vector result.

The first form is simpler, because it avoids the confusion you highlighted, and makes the physical meaning of the term (looking for the change along the direction of $u$, which is what $u\cdot\nabla$ projects out).

Comment: Just to be clear if $\vec{v}$ is a vector and $\mathbf{M}$ a matrix, then $$ \vec{v} \cdot \mathbf{M} = \vec{v}^\top \mathbf{M} = \left( \mathbf{M}^\top \vec{v} \right)^\top$$ with the last being the transpose of a matrix-vector product, but using the traspose of $\mathbf{M}$ for the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I find $\nabla\vec u$ to be slightly ambiguous notation, which should be either avoided or explained when it is first introduced (which [can be done](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.01931)).

Usually, however, it refers to a matrix whose entries are
$$
(\nabla\vec u)_{ij} = \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i},
$$
and the notation $\vec u \cdot \nabla \vec u$ is usually the left-hand vector-matrix product, giving you the vector
$$
\left( \vec u \cdot \nabla \vec u \right)_j = \sum_i u_i \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}.
$$
Of course, this coincides with
$$
\left( (\vec u \cdot \nabla) \vec u \right)_j = \left[\sum_i u_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right] u_j,
$$
i.e., the two notations are equivalent.

In the terms that you describe,

> It's weird because the dot is a dot product in (u⋅∇), but ∇u being a gradient of a vector field, would (presumably) produce a (jacobian?) matrix which would turn that dot-product dot into a regular vector-matrix multiply where I have to swap the matrix and the vector (because as it's written, the vector will be on the left side).

this isn't particularly weird at all: dot products and vector-matrix products are both special cases of [tensor contractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction), i.e., taking two objects with indices and summing over one paired index. The only differences between the two are superficial and cosmetic.