# What does an upside down delta mean - covariant vectors?

Tags: definition, differentiation, notation

I was scrolling through a wiki article on [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity#Terminal_speed_in_a_creeping_flow) when I spotted an upside down delta. What does this symbol mean? How is it applied in other contexts?

EDIT: If possible could someone expand upon "a covariant vector made of space derivatives?" I sort of understand how a vector can be made up of partial derivatives, but what does covariant mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\nabla$, $\cdot \nabla$, $\nabla \cdot$, $\nabla^2$ - What do they do?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/750764/)

Comment: Yes @Amit this looks like it answers my question thoroughly!

Comment: Re: Edit -- This question is now closed as a duplicate, and in general posts should contain one question without being later edited to widen their scope. You may of course post a new question -- but I strongly suggest that you first carry out a search to see if a similar question to your new one also exists. For more general guidance on how to ask a good question [click here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5):

That is the [Nabla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol), and it just means the covariant vector made of space derivatives.

Edit:
$$\vec\nabla f=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}
\end  {pmatrix}$$

Comment: What is a covariant vector? Or space derivatives? But thank you for answering my question despite my ignorance.

Comment: Check the new edit. I think you are far from understanding what is needed to explain covariant, but space derivatives should be understandable.

Comment: Oh I see a vector made of partial derivatives using Cartesian coordinates. I'd assume this vector can take many forms, 1x3, 2x3, 3x3... or does that exclude it from being "covariant." Also your right, I probably will not be able to understand covariance.

Comment: @Carlo Have you seen vectors that are 2x3, 3x3, etc.?

Comment: @Ghoster I’m kind of a goof I got mixed up between matrices and vectors. I’ve learned a tiny bit more about grad and its a function that converts scalars into vector fields.