# Scalar geometric product ambiguity involving derivatives

Tags: clifford-algebra

I'm working on deriving the Euler equations for a perfect fluid from the conservation of the energy-momentum tensor and I've found some difficulties with the notation.

Given two vector fields, $v(x)$, $a(x)$ and the vector derivative $\nabla$. If you form an expression like

\begin{equation}
(v \cdot \nabla) a = (v^\mu \nabla_\mu ) a,
\end{equation}

it would mean that $(v \cdot \nabla)$ is a scalar differential operator (the directional derivative) acting on $a$.

However, if you construct the expression

\begin{equation}
( \nabla \cdot v) a = (\nabla_\mu v^\mu ) a,
\end{equation}

it would mean that you are multiplying the divergence of $v$ with $a$.

Considering that in Geometric Algebra the scalar product between vectors is symmetric, should not both expressions be equivalent?

Comment: A number of comments deleted, but [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4391090/166791) should still be linked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetry of the inner product is not particular to geometric algebra, it is something from standard vector calculus. In both contexts, the two mean very different things as $\nabla$ operates on $v$ in one case and $a$ in the other; in fact, you may see some authors prefer to write the directional derivative as,
$$ \left(v\cdot\nabla\right)a=v\cdot\left(\nabla a\right)\tag{1} $$
to indicate that $\nabla$ acts on $a$ and is dotted with $v$ ([these are indeed equivalent](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160229/25301), though I prefer using the first form).

I suspect that your confusion arises when trying to write these as,
$$
\left(v\cdot\nabla\right)a=\langle v\nabla\rangle_0a=\langle\nabla v\rangle_0a=\left(\nabla\cdot v\right)a\tag{2}
$$
and assuming they are equal due to the symmetry of the grade-0 product. However, $\nabla$ in this case is an operator, rather than an ordinary vector, so there are particular rules one needs to assert when considering expressions utilizing vectors:<sup>1</sup>

1. In the absence of brackets, $\nabla$ operates on the object to its immediate right.
2. When $\nabla$ is followed by brackets, it operates on all terms in the brackets.
3. When $\nabla$ acts on an object to which it is not adjacent, use overdots to indicate scope.

Thus, you would write (2) using Rule #3 as:
$$
\left\{\left(v\cdot\nabla\right)a=\langle v\dot\nabla\rangle_0\dot a=\langle\dot\nabla v\rangle_0\dot a\right\}\neq\left\{\langle\dot\nabla\dot v\rangle_0a=\left(\nabla\cdot v\right)a\right\}
$$
which makes it more clear that the two expressions are not equivalent.

<sup>1. I have seen some authors use notation like $\langle v\nabla^aa\rangle_1$ to indicate that $\nabla$ acts on $a$. The rules here are also given by Hestenes; I believe that both Bromborsky and Doran & Lasenby also follow these rules.</sup>

Comment: Fun fact: using Rule 1, $\dot a\dot\nabla$ is a sensible expression, as it still indicates that $\nabla$ is operating on $a$.

Comment: Thank you very much, with the dot notation it is very clear. So basically one needs to be careful when to apply the symmetries of the products when using operators instead of multivectors.

Comment: Equation (1) is wrong.  In geometric algebra, $\nabla a$ represents *two* things: a derivative operator acting on $a$ and a geometric product between two vectors - which makes $\nabla a$ the sum of a scalar and a bivector.  But the dot product of a vector with such a sum is always zero, so the right-hand side is zero.  That's not true of the left-hand side.  Here, $v \cdot \nabla$ is a *scalar* derivative operator, which can certainly be nonzero.  The rest of the explanation is basically correct, though.