# Inner product of the material derivative

Tags: fluid-dynamics, definition, differentiation, vector-fields, navier-stokes

I have question about the inner product of the material derivative.

$$\frac{D\mathbf{v}}{Dt}=\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}+\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{v}.$$

How can you calculate the second term inner product?

$$\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & \cdots & a_{13} \\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\a_{31} & \cdots & a_{33}\end{bmatrix}.$$

I wrote the right dyad as $a$. The length of the vectors and height of the matrix does not match. How can you calculate it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advection operator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160229/)

Comment: See also pretty much every other question linked there as well.

Comment: @Kyle Thank you so much. And the answer explains my question. I may delete this sled following the StackExchange's rule.